Copy data from one MS Access database to another
I have two MS Access databases, one with a lot of data in it and the other one almost empty. I need to migrate all the data from the first database to the second. They have the same table names and almost the same columns names, but the second database has more columns.
So I want to copy the data from database one to database two if the columns have the same name.
This is because I updated a billing software, and the databases are not fully compatible.
I only tried copy/pasting the data manually, but there are about 20 tables with +20 columns on each database, and it's a very tedious work.

In the new database, link the table from the old. Then create append queries using the linked tables as source and the local tables as target.

Programmatic Solution for the problem
Made solution using MS Access with VBA, for data migration use DAO (Data Access Object) and ADO (ActiveX Database Object).
This code has been successfully implemented in MS Access 2016. This code is resided in the 2nd database.
Steps in implementation

Create two separate ADODB.Connection with both the database
Then get list of tables from both the database
Then crossmatch Table by Column in both the database
IF matched then append data from that table of 1st database to 2nd database

The comment on the code is sufficient to understand the program.
Private Sub AddDataFrom1stDB()
    Dim currDB As String
    currDB = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & CurrentProject.Name '2nd Database'
    Dim ExtConn As New ADODB.Connection, LocConn As New ADODB.Connection, strFind As String
    cmnDLG.DialogTitle = "Open Access DB file"
    cmnDLG.FileName = ""
    cmnDLG.DefaultExt = ".Accdb"
    cmnDLG.Filter = "EXCEL files (*.Accdb)|*.AccDB|All files(*.*)|*.*"
    cmnDLG.ShowOpen
    Dim TargetDB As String
    TargetDB = cmnDLG.FileName 'Get File name of 1st Database'
    ExtConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = " & TargetDB & "; Persist Security Info=False;"
    ExtConn.Open '1st Database Connection'
    Set LocConn = CurrentProject.Connection '2nd Database connection'
    
    
    Dim ExtRS As New ADODB.Recordset, LocRS As New ADODB.Recordset
    ExtRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient: LocRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    arrCriteria = Array(Empty, Empty, Empty, “Table”)
    Set ExtRS = ExtConn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables, arrCriteria) 'Get Table List of 1st Database'
    Set LocRS = LocConn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables, arrCriteria) 'Get Table List of 2nd Database'
    strFind = "Table_Type='TABLE'"
    LocRS.Filter = strFind: ExtRS.Filter = strFind
    If LocRS.RecordCount > 0 Then LocRS.MoveFirst
    Dim LocTbl As String
    
    Dim rsLTbl As New ADODB.Recordset, rsRTbl As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rsLFld As New ADODB.Recordset, rsRFld As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cno As Integer, switch As Boolean
    
    Do Until LocRS.EOF '*1 comparing table list based on 2nd Databases Table List'
        switch = True
        LocTbl = LocRS.Fields("TABLE_NAME").Value
        lstTables.AddItem (LocTbl)
        strFind = "TABLE_NAME='" & LocTbl & "'"
        If ExtRS.RecordCount > 0 Then ExtRS.MoveFirst
        ExtRS.Find strFind
        If Not ExtRS.EOF Then
            Set rsLFld = ListTableColumns(LocTbl, currDB)   ' Get Column Name and Type from 2nd Database'
            Set rsRFld = ListTableColumns(LocTbl, TargetDB) ' Get Column Name and Type from 1st Database'
            If rsLFld.RecordCount = rsRFld.RecordCount Then ' Comparing number of fields in two table'
                rsLFld.Sort = "Column_Name": rsRFld.Sort = "Column_Name"
                Do Until rsLFld.EOF   ' Checking Column name and Column Type'
                    strFind = "Column_Name='" & rsLFld!Column_Name & "'"
                    rsRFld.MoveFirst
                    rsRFld.Find strFind
                    If Not rsRFld.EOF Then
                        If rsLFld!Column_Type = rsRFld!Column_Type Then
                            
                        Else
                            switch = False
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                        
                    End If
                  rsLFld.MoveNext
                Loop
                If switch = True Then 'Entering data from 1st Database to 2nd Database'
                    If rsLTbl.State = adStateOpen Then rsLTbl.Close
                    rsLTbl.Open "SELECT * FROM " & LocTbl, LocConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
                    If rsRTbl.State = adStateOpen Then rsRTbl.Close
                    rsRTbl.Open "SELECT * FROM " & LocTbl, ExtConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
                    Do Until rsRTbl.EOF
                        rsLTbl.AddNew
                        For cno = 0 To rsRTbl.Fields.Count - 1
                            rsLTbl.Fields(rsRTbl.Fields(cno).Name).Value = rsRTbl.Fields(rsRTbl.Fields(cno).Name).Value
                        Next
                        rsLTbl.Update
                        rsRTbl.MoveNext
                    Loop
                End If
            End If
        End If
        LocRS.MoveNext
    Loop '1*'
    MsgBox "Done...", vbInformation
End Sub



Public Function ListTableColumns(sTableName As String, xDB As String) As ADODB.Recordset
    'Creating list of Column name and column type of table'
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    
    Set db = OpenDatabase(xDB)
    Set tdf = db.TableDefs(sTableName)  ' Replace with your table name'

    rs.Fields.Append "Column_Name", adVarChar, 200
    rs.Fields.Append "Column_Type", adVarChar, 100
    rs.Open
    For Each fld In tdf.Fields
        rs.AddNew
        rs!Column_Name = fld.Name: rs!Column_Type = fld.Type
        rs.Update
    Next fld
    
    Set ListTableColumns = rs
End Function


